# Writing links in angular app when using Apache URL rewrites

Tags: angularjs, apache, url-rewriting, routes

I'm working on an angular app that is in a structure like this:

```
/dir1/dir2/myApp
```

There are rewrite rules in place, so that when someone comes from:

```
customURL/myApp
```

they hit my app. When I am in my local environment, the links that I use for routing just look like:

```
href="#/route"
```

and that all works fine, but when I hit the app from the custom URL, I end up on my index page and when I click one of the links, it reloads the page and takes me away from my custom URL structure and back to:

```
/dir1/dir2/myApp/#/route
```

I currently have fixed this by making all my hrefs look like this:

```
href="/myApp/#/route"
```

Then when I come in from the custom url and click a link, the url changes to this and there is no reload:

```
customUrl/myApp/#/route
```

That is the desired effect and it all works, but having to add that extra path in to every single href sort of feels wrong, and I'm wondering if there is a better way.

I have read through a lot of documentation and experimented with html5Mode, but this is the only way I have been able to achieve what I want.

If anyone with more experience with this has any tips or even thinks this is a perfectly good way of doing it, I'd really appreciate the feedback.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would used ng-href="#/route"

very specific case, I can't reproduce on my machine,
so first of all do console.log($location) and see what your host is

if something what you expected, then just play around right href, try with and without '#' or '/'